# Como atribuir "selected" à uma option dinâmica?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

Estou populando um `SELECT` à partir dum `JSON` recebido via `AJAX` da seguinte forma:

```
$.each(parsedData, function(i, produto) {
    $('select#produtos').append(
        $('<option></option>').val(produto.cod_produto).html(produto.descricao)
    );
});
```

Estou tentando atribuir o `SELECTED` nessas `options`, porém sem sucesso. Utilizando:

```
$('<option></option>').val(produto.cod_produto).html(produto.descricao).attr('selected', true)
```

Ou mesmo com `.attr('selected','selected')` e recebo o erro:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Continuando as tentativas:

```
.prop("selected", "selected")
```

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).val(...).html(...).prop is not a function

Comment: Você quer fazer o selected apenas do primeiro item? já tentou fazer um callback?

Comment: Quer o select em um `option` com um valor em especifico?

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues eu irei atribuir a um valor em específico, não tentei callback.

Comment: Sim, @Miguel. Exatamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu costumo fazer isso sem utilizar tantas tags Jquery, particularmente me perco menos com html. Faria algo do tipo:

```
 var selected = "";
 if(isSelected){
  selected="selected";
 }

$('select#produtos').append("<option value='"+produto.cod_produto+"' " +selected+" >"+produto.descricao+"</option>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Creio que deve ser isso

```js
var val_produto = 3; // value do produto que queremos selecionar
var descricao = 'produto muito bom';
var opts = '';

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // tento simular o seu ciclo each
   opts += '<option value="' +i+ '">' +descricao+ '_' +i+ '</option>';
}

$('select#produtos').append(opts); // fazemos o append a todas as opts depois do ciclo para não ficar muito pesado
// o produto que tem o valor val_produto vai ficar selected
$('select#produtos option[value="' +val_produto+ '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="produtos">
</select>
```

Fiquei sem perceber bem se quer mais do que uma opção selecionada. De qualquer maneira aqui está para várias opções (note o "`multiple`" no `<select>`):

```js
var val_produtos = [1, 3, 7, 9]; // value dos produtos que queremos selecionar
var descricao = 'produto muito bom';
var opts = '';

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // tento simular o seu ciclo each
   if(val_produtos.indexOf(i) > -1) {
       opts += '<option value="' +i+ '" selected>' +descricao+ '_' +i+ '</option>';
   }
   else {
       opts += '<option value="' +i+ '">' +descricao+ '_' +i+ '</option>';
   }
}

$('select#produtos').append(opts); // fazemos o append a todas as opts depois do ciclo para não ficar muito pesado
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="produtos" multiple>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma abordagem boa é percorrer o for criando apenas uma váriavel que conterá todo o objeto option a ser inserido no html.
esta opção tem mais desempenho por não estar acessando a cada loop o html para inserir um novo valor.

Como o item selecionado pode ser apenas um da para definir um if com a condição de sua escolha para que este item seja o selecionado.

**Exemplo:**

```js
var parsedData = [{
  cod_produto: 1,
  descricao: "Item 1"
}, {
  cod_produto: 2,
  descricao: "Item 2"
}, {
  cod_produto: 3,
  descricao: "Me Seleciona!"
}, {
  cod_produto: 4,
  descricao: "Item 4"
}];

var option = "";

$.each(parsedData, function(key, val) {
  if (val.cod_produto === 3) {
    option += '<option value=' + val.cod_produto + ' selected>' + val.descricao + '</option>';
  } else {
    option += '<option value=' + val.cod_produto + '>' + val.descricao + '</option>';
  }
});

$("#select").append(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">

</select>
```

Referência: [Criar elemento no HTML com JavaScript (appendChild vs innerHTML)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/120708/criar-elemento-no-html-com-javascript-appendchild-vs-innerhtml/120999#120999)