# Como interagir com HTML criado com javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Eu estou criando um sitema de posts que vai ser atualizado por ajax, porém quando adiciona mais um post o menu lateral não funciona. Como atualizar sem fazer o menu parar?

Esse é o código que estou usando, coloqui um botão ao lado para simular o ajax atualizando os post, porém depois de adicionar mais um post o menu não funciona.

```js
         var lower = document.querySelectorAll(".context-btn"),
             context = document.querySelectorAll(".context-menu");
        
         let lowerLength = lower.length;
         for (let i = 0; i < lowerLength; i++) {

             onLowerClick(lower[i], i);
         }

         document.addEventListener("click", hideContextMenu, false);

         function onLowerClick(elemt, num) {

             elemt.addEventListener("click", function() {

                 event.stopPropagation();
                 showContextMenu(this, num);

             });
         }

         function showContextMenu(elemt, menu) {

             hideContextMenu(menu);
             elemt.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('context-menu--visible');
         }

         function hideContextMenu(save) {

             let contextLength = context.length;
             for (let i = 0; i < contextLength; i++) {

                 if (save != i) context[i].classList.remove("context-menu--visible");

             }
         }
        
        var corpo = '<div id="base"> <div class="nav"> <div class="context-container">';
        corpo += '<button class="context-btn"> <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i> </button>';
        corpo += '<div class="context-menu"> <ul class="context-list"><li class="context-menu-item">Edit this Post</li><li class="context-menu-item">Alert this Post</li><li class="context-menu-item">Delete thid Post</li> </ul> </div>'; 
        corpo += '</div></div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore repudiandae, cum placeat minima. Aliquam natus mollitia, alias fugiat ea provident debitis eius reprehenderit, illum dolorem at fuga in tempora fugit.</div';
        
        function add(){
            document.getElementById('corpo').innerHTML += corpo;
        }
```

```css
 *{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
        *:focus{outline:none;}
        body{ background-color: #e3e3e3; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;}
        
        #base{ width: 50%; height: auto; min-height: 200px; margin: 15px auto;}
        
        .nav{
            width: 100%; height: 50px;
            padding: 10px;
            
            box-sizing: border-box;
            background-color: #3F51B5;
            border-radius: 3px;
            text-align: right;
            
        }
        .context-container{ position: relative; }
        
        .context-btn{
            width: 27px;
            border: none;
            background-color: #3F51B5;
            border-radius: 50%;
            color: #fff;
        
        } 
        
        .context-btn:hover{ background-color: #5260b0;}
        .context-btn:active{ background-color: #646fab;}
        
        .context-menu{
            visibility: hidden;
            position: absolute;
            right: 10px; 
            z-index: 1; 
            
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14),0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.2),0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
            box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14),0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.2),0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
            
            -webkit-transition: transform .3s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
            -o-transition: transform .3s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
            transition: transform .3s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1); 
            
            -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            -ms-transform: scale(0);
            -o-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0);
            
            -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
            -moz-transform-origin: 100% 0;
            -ms-transform-origin: 100% 0;
            -o-transform-origin: 100% 0;
            transform-origin: 100% 0;
        }
        
        .context-menu--visible{
            visibility: visible;
            -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            -ms-transform: scale(1);
            -o-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
        }
        
        .context-list{
            width: auto; height: auto;
            padding: 8px 0;
            background: #fff;
            border-radius: 3px;
            text-align: left;
            
        }   
        
        .context-menu-item{
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0 16px;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 46px;
            color: #757575; 
        
        }
        
        .context-menu-item:hover{ background: #eee;}
```

```html
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<button onclick="add();">add</button>
<div id="corpo">
    <div id="base">
        <div class="nav">
            <div class="context-container">
                <button class="context-btn">
                  <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
                </button>
                <div class="context-menu">
                    <ul class="context-list">
                        <li class="context-menu-item">Edit this Post</li>
                        <li class="context-menu-item">Alert this Post</li>
                        <li class="context-menu-item">Delete thid Post</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore repudiandae, cum placeat minima. Aliquam natus mollitia, alias fugiat ea provident debitis eius reprehenderit, illum dolorem at fuga in tempora fugit.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Eu ainda sou muito novato, mas sugeria que usasses a propriedade `onclick="myFunction(postID)"` do botão para chamar a função do menu, e podias colocar um `id` diferente para cada post gerado (1,2,3...) <button class="context-btn" id="postID"> e usa-lo na função do menu para o que precisares.

Comment: @ihavenokia eu pensei nisso mas como vai ser um sistema dinâmico ficaria meio inviável!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema principal é este trecho de código:

```
document.getElementById('corpo').innerHTML += corpo;
```

Esta forma faz com que você perca os eventos anexados aos seus elementos (grosseiramente falando). Ao invés utilize métodos como:

```
elemento.appendChild(filho);
```

Ou com JQuery:

```
$('#elemento').append(filho);
```

Existem outros problemas com o código acima, mas agora estou sem tempo para mais detalhes. Deixo você com a correção que fiz. vlw.

http://codepen.io/renatocolaco/pen/JEGJPa

Mais informações sobre appendChild vs innerHTML [Criar elemento no HTML com JavaScript (appendChild vs innerHTML)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/120708/criar-elemento-no-html-com-javascript-appendchild-vs-innerhtml)

Comment: mais informações: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/120708/criar-elemento-no-html-com-javascript-appendchild-vs-innerhtml

Comment: Eu estou usando js puro, e coloquei o que você disse, deu alguns erros mas agora adiciona, porém só o primeiro post funciona o menu, os outros que são adicionados não!

Comment: Acabei de fazer um testes e vi que o erro está na hora de atribuir o click ao botão, pois só reconhece os iniciais do início da contagem, vou ter fazer o código recarregar a variável de contagem toda vez que adicionar um novo post!

Comment: Veja no exemplo que deixei como faço a atribuição do evento click. $('corpo').click ('click','.context-btn',funcionar()) ... Dessa forma vc n precisa fazer mais nenhuma contagem. E se a resposta foi útil, não esqueça de marcar como respondida. Vlw.

Comment: É que eu uso js puro, e não estou conseguindo passar do jquery para o código puro!