# Inserir Tags pelo Console

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe, console

Preciso inserir Tags em um site pelo console. Para ser mais específico, quero adicionar uma TAG `<iframe></iframe>`.

Já tentei usar o `document.createElement('tag')`, após isso adicionar os atributos da tag pelo appendChild. mas não tive sucesso.

Também tentei criar uma  e adicionar a tag e atributos através de textos, mas não funcionou.

```
document.createElement('div').innerHTML="<iframe id="" frameborder="0" style="" scrolling="auto" src="" allowfullscreen></iframe> "
```

Comment: Pelo console? Não seria pelo javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seguinte código deve servir:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.id = '';
iframe.frameBorder = '0';
iframe.style = '';
iframe.scrolling = 'auto';
iframe.src = '';
iframe.allowFullscreen = 'true';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Primeiro [cria um elemento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120708) com [Document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)
, depois atribui valores ás propriedades do elemento (que representam os atributos do elemento) e no fim adiciona o elemento ([iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/iframe)) ao elemento [body](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body) com o método [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/DOM/element.appendChild)
.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `createElement()`, seguido do `appendChild()`.

```js
var target = document.getElementById('target');

var elemento = document.createElement('iframe');
elemento.frameBorder = 0;
elemento.style = "";
elemento.scrolling = "";
elemento.src = "";
elemento.id = "novo-iframe";

target.appendChild(elemento);

console.log(document.getElementById('novo-iframe'));
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="target"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu último código não funcionou pois você não está inserindo o elemento criado na sua página, além de não está escapando as *" (aspas)* dos atributos.

Você também pode usar [**insertAdjacentHTML**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) para inserir um código HTML em sua página.

```
element.insertAdjacentHTML("posição", "código-html);
```

Para controlar onde você quer o elemento, basta adicionar um dos valores abaixo no lugar de *posição*

> **beforebegin:** Antes do Elemento

> **afterbegin:** Dentro do elemento e antes do seu primeiro filho

> **beforeend:** Dentro do elemento e depois do seu último filho

> **afterend:** Após o elemento

```js
// Captura o elemento onde queremos adicionar
var target = document.querySelector('#target');

// Código do iframe
var elemento = '<iframe frameborder="0" id="novo-iframe" src="/"></iframe>';

// Adicionamos o iframe dentro do elemento capturado
target.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', elemento);

// Exibidos o código do iframe criado no console
console.log(document.getElementById('novo-iframe'));
```

```css
iframe {
  height: 14em;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

---

#### Com jQuery

```js
$('#target').append('<iframe frameborder="0" id="novo-iframe" src="/"></iframe>');
```

```css
iframe {
  height: 14em;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="target"></div>
```