# Exibir valor da variável do script no HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Criei um script básico para gerar um valor aleatório de 1 a 100. Mas, quando eu abria o html na qual eu criei o script ele só aparecia no console da pagina e não na pagina na qual eu criei.
Como faria para o resultado aparecer na tela?

```
<html>
<script>

function rollDice() {
  let roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  console.log(`Rolled: ${roll}`);
}

rollDice()
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Criar elemento no HTML com JavaScript (appendChild vs innerHTML)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/120708/criar-elemento-no-html-com-javascript-appendchild-vs-innerhtml)

Comment: Coloca essa linha na função document.write("<span style='color:red'>Rolled:"+roll+"</span>");

Comment: Nem precisa de função basta colocar o script onde quer que apareça na página <script>let roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
document.write("<span style='color:red'>Rolled:"+roll+"</span>");</script>

Comment: mais Leo eu estou implementando esse script e um outro html mais exatamente: eu coloco esse script em um input e quando eu clico no input a pagina ela recarrega e fica completamente branca e com somente o valor do dado você consegue ajeitar isso?

Comment: <input type="image" src="img/dice.png" id="sanibotao" onclick="rollDice()"> eu coloquei seu codigo em function para testar

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar um elemento HTML via Javascript e adicionar o número no elemento criado.

Exemplo:

```js
function rollDice() {
  let roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  console.log(`Rolled: ${roll}`);
  let span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerHTML = 'Numero Random: ' + roll
  document.body.appendChild(span)
}

rollDice()
```

Explicando o codigo:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

   let span = document.createElement('span');

> Em um documento HTML, o método Document.createElement() cria o elemento HTML especificado ou um HTMLUnknownElement se o nome do elemento dado não for conhecido.

2. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

   span.innerHTML = 'Numero Random: ' + roll

> A propriedade Element.innerHTML define ou obtém a sintaxe HTML ou XML descrevendo os elementos descendentes.

3. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

   document.body.appendChild(span)

> Adiciona um nó ao final da lista de filhos de um nó pai especificado. Se o nó já existir no documento, ele é removido de seu nó pai atual antes de ser adicionado ao novo pai.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, peguei o seu código e refiz com algumas alterações, segue abaixo:

```
 <div id = random> </div>
        <script>
            function rollDice() {
            let roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
            return roll;
            }
            document.getElementById("random").innerHTML = rollDice();
            
        </script>
```

Pra ser mostrado no documento html vc precisa utilizar o **innerHTML** por meio do um elemento ****DOM** getElementById**.

Comment: mais estou tentando botar isso em um input para quando eu apertar esse input rodar um valor aleatório coloquei o valor "random" no input e não funcionou, oque eu coloco para trocar o valor

Comment: <input type="image" src="img/dice.png" id="sanibotao" onclick="random">

Comment: Cara, realmente o resultado tem que ser mostrada no input? Eu pergunto isso porque ao pé da letra o a tag 'input' ele foi designado para receber uma entrada ou melhor informações em vários formatos. Sendo eles de texto, imagens, data e etc.