# Como mostrar resultados da API no HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, api

Estou com um projeto onde tenho um input HTML, onde envio o link da imagem de um carro, vai para uma IA que busca em uma API. Até aí tudo certo, o resultado volta certinho no console. O problema é que eu queria saber como faço para levar o resultado desse JSON, para o HTML. Segue o código abaixo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="data"></div>
    <input type="text" name="link" id="link">
    <input type="submit" name="button" onclick="clicouBotao()">
    <script src="https://algorithmia.com/v1/clients/js/algorithmia-0.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        function clicouBotao(){
         var input = document.getElementById('link').value;
        Algorithmia.client("simwTGCAoebHnAZc7rgS6NkkxxV1")
            .algo("LgoBE/CarMakeandModelRecognition/0.4.8?timeout=700") 
            .pipe(input)
            .then(function(output) {
            console.log(output);               
            });
        }              
    </script>
</body>
</html
```

Comment: Como você quer exibir no HTML? Só o JSON puro mesmo? Qual está sendo a dificuldade?

Comment: Eu recebo o JSON com os resultados certinho, só que no console, então eu queria passar o resultado e exibi-lo no HTML da página, pra que fique visível. Consegue me ajudar? Não tenho muito conhecimento em JSON, obrigado desde já.

Comment: Se não sabe criar um elemento no HTML com JavaScript, dê uma olhada aqui:  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120708/100416

Comment: Obrigado mano, de verdade. Voou tentar aqui, conte comigo também, sei pouco mas posso ajudar, vlw.

Comment: Só mais uma pergunta amigo, como eu insiro o meu JSON aqui no Js? (Não sei nada de JS)

Comment: Um exemplo: `const pre = document.createElement('pre');pre.innerText = JSON.stringify(output, null, 4);document.body.append(pre);`. Não recomendo dar o `append` no `body`, faça como ficar melhor no seu HTML, isso é só um exemplo (são três linhas, quebre-as após o `;`). Se tiver dificuldades, sugiro que crie um exemplo simples (leia [mcve]) e clique em [edit] para melhorar sua pergunta.

Comment: Valeu cara, mas o console no browser diz que "Uncaught ReferenceError: output is not defined
    at (index):38"

Comment: GustavoDaniel o código que o @RafaelTavares sugeriou tem que ser colocado dentro do function do then(), o método é assincrono e não sincrono, fora o escopo da variavel.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Como já comentado, você pode:

1. Criar um elemento HTML `<pre>`, que exibirá seu JSON sem alterar a
   formatação;

   ```
   const pre = document.createElement('pre');
   ```
2. Transformar o JSON recebido em uma string com indentação e inseri-la como texto em seu elemento `<pre>`;

   ```
   pre.textContent = JSON.stringify(output, null, 4);
   ```
3. Inserir o elemento no seu documento HTML, após o seu `<input type="submit">`, por exemplo.

   ```
   const input = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');
   input.parentNode.insertBefore(pre, input.nextSibling);
   ```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="data"></div>
  <input type="text" name="link" id="link">
  <input type="submit" name="button" onclick="clicouBotao()">
  <script src="https://algorithmia.com/v1/clients/js/algorithmia-0.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    function clicouBotao() {
      var input = document.getElementById('link').value;
      Algorithmia.client("simwTGCAoebHnAZc7rgS6NkkxxV1")
        .algo("LgoBE/CarMakeandModelRecognition/0.4.8?timeout=700")
        .pipe(input)
        .then(function(output) {
          const pre = document.createElement('pre');
          pre.textContent = JSON.stringify(output, null, 4);
          const input = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');
          input.parentNode.insertBefore(pre, input.nextSibling);
        });
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Valeu amigo! Deu super certo! Se não for muito incômodo (rsrs), poderia me ajudar as chaves e os colchetes do JSON,  e voltar apenas os nomes por favor? tipo os {
   "result": [
      {
         "body_style": "Sedan"

Comment: Que falta de amor você têm no coração para formatar o JSON com 3 espaços, BSdoukos? Há o time dos que formatam com 2, os que formatam com 4, mas 3 é a primeira vez que vejo hahaha.

Comment: @GustavoDaniel Não sei se entendi bem a sua ideia. Você só quer remover as chaves e colchetes ou quer manipular o JSON para exibir apenas os valores retornados, de maneira mais legível? De qualquer forma, talvez valha a pena criar uma nova pergunta clarificando melhor seu problema.

Comment: @RafaelTavares Eu mesmo sempre indento com 4 espaços, nem sei por que coloquei 3 ali. Até editei a resposta :)

Comment: @BSdoukos, então cara, eu só queria que o retorno do JSON ficasse mais legível